# Hopf-Rinow theorem from do Carmo's book, proof problem.

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading do Carmo's book Riemannian geometry and I have a problem. At the proof of Hopf-Rinow theorem, more precisely at c.)=>d.) ($M$ complete metric space => $M$ geodezically complete space). I don't Understand the last step of the proof. [image]

Namely the fact that $\text{exp}_{\gamma(s_n)}(B_\delta(0))\supset W.$ And why $g$ extends $\gamma$ beyond $s_0?$

Comment: This is the definition of normal neighborhood (see Proposition 3.6) and a totally normal neighborhood (see Theorem 3.7).

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Thanks!